# Does vim support spell checking in the command line?

Tags: command-line, spell-checking

I suspect that it doesn't. I don't see anything about it in the documentation(`:h spell`), but I'd love to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in the command line that I know of since I'm pretty sure the command line prompt doesn't highlight text.  But, you can enable spell checking in the *command window*.

Press `ctrl-f` on the command line or press `q:` in normal mode.  This brings up the command window which can be treated almost like any other buffer.  From here you can run `:set spell` to enable spell checking.  However, the command window uses `filetype=vim` which doesn't show spelling errors for some reason.  Running `set filetype=` to disable the syntax highlighting allows the spell check highlight to show.

You can use an `autocmd` to set up the command window when it opens:

```
autocmd CmdwinEnter * if &ft =~# 'vim' | setlocal spell ft= | endif
```

This is a better solution based on your comment below about using `input()`:

```
autocmd CmdwinEnter * if getcmdwintype() == '@' | setlocal spell | endif
```

This will enable spellcheck for the `input()` history window.

From `:h cmdwin-char`:

```
The character used for the pattern indicates the type of command-line:
    :   normal Ex command
    >   debug mode command debug-mode
    /   forward search string
    ?   backward search string
    =   expression for "= expr-register
    @   string for input()
    -   text for :insert or :append
```

If your version of Vim does not have `getcmdwintype()`, you could use a expression map since `getcmdtype()` is only available when editing the command line or an expression mapping:

```
cnoremap <silent><expr> <c-f> getcmdtype() == '@' ? "\<c-f>:setlocal spell\<cr>" : "\<c-f>"
```

Comment: Nice! While not a perfect solution this actually works pretty well. I'll wait for a bit to see if anyone has any other ideas, but if not I'll definitely give you the green check :). Side note: I am using the input to an `input()` command and when I press `Ctrl`+`F` there the `filetype` is already set to nothing. I also have a hot key for turning spell check on so it all works pretty well.

Comment: Other note, I think that the `vim` filetype will do spell checking, but only in strings and comments. (Which is pretty normal as far as spell checking code goes)

Comment: @Tumbler41 I saw that in `syntax/vim.vim`, but I didn't see spell check working in strings and comments when I was testing it. Maybe I have a syntax file overriding it somewhere.

Comment: @Tumbler41 I updated the answer with what I think is better in your case of using `input()`

Comment: It seems that `getcmdwintype()` is not installed on my version of vim. Looks like it was added in version [7.4.383](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/w0OMuAnkjcI) It would appear that I have 7.4.0 (I think although `vim --version` only says "7.4" grrrrr) Do I have to compile vim to get a patch that isn't a major release? (i.e. 7.5)

Comment: @Tumbler41 I think so, yeah.  But, it's possible to enable spelling without `getcmdwintime()`.  I updated the answer.